# Using an `and` condition in a `select` behaves (sometimes) like an `or`

Tags: jq

I need to find those ethernet interfaces, which are up.

I tried this:

```
$ ip -d -j a s | jq 'map(select ((.link_type == "ether") and (.flags[] | contains 
("UP")))) | map(.ifname)'
```

But it returns two results,

```json
[
  "enp0s3",
  "enp0s3"
]
```

although `ip` lists this interface only once.

```
$ ip -d -j a s | jq 'map(.ifname)'
```

```json
[
  "lo",
  "enp0s3",
  "enp0s8"
]
```

It seems to me that the `and` in the `select` behaves like an `or`. It returns those interfaces, which have `.link_type = "ether"` or `.flags[] | contains ("UP")`.

But when I try the same with a more basic example,

```
$ jq 'map(select((. > 1) and (. < 3)))' <<<'[1, 2, 3]'
```

it works as expected:

```json
[
  2
]
```

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of common pitfalls associated with using `select(..)`. You are actually expanding the data twice, once w.r.t. to the root level and once again with `.flags[]` leading to [combinatorial explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion#Computing)

The solution would be to move `.flags[]` outside select as below

```
map(.flags[] as $x | select ((.link_type == "ether") and ( $x | contains ("UP"))))
```

Also it seems the flags can take the values `UP` and `LOWER_UP`, if you were looking for an exact match, use an equality operator `==` or a strict regex match, e.g. with `test(..)`

A simple lookup for just `UP` in case if you are *not* running into the above explosion would be to just do

```
map(select( (.link_type == "ether") and (.flags[] == "UP") ))
```

Comment: The sub-string search of `contains` was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that `contains` does a sub-string search.

Changing `.flags[] | contains ("UP")` to `.flags[] | . == "UP"` fixes the problem:

```
$ ip -d -j a s | jq 'map (select (.link_type == "ether")) | map (select 
(.flags[] | . == "UP")) | map(.ifname)'
```

```json
[
  "enp0s3"
]
```

Comment: `.flags[] == "UP"` is sufficient

Comment: So is using `map` just once: `jq' map(select(... and ...).ifname)'`